# How do I view a notificaiton without clearing it on Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop?

Tags: notification

I'm attempting to connect from a remote desktop, but this notification pops up when I try to connect from the other computer.

Unfortunately, I can't figure how I could possibly read this notification. The text is truncated and clicking anywhere just clears it.
How do I actually view the notification?

Also, would be fantastic if someone could also tell me why the remote desktop can't connect and how to fix it.

[image: Unreadable notification]

Ubuntu 23.10

Comment: I'm using 23.10

Comment: I figured out the issue with xrdp. I can't be logged in on the real machine while connecting from remote desktop on the other PC at the same time.